# Lang key values can not be seen in template parser loop - Codeigniter 3.1.4

Tags: php, codeigniter, parsing, templates, codeigniter-3

I have a problem to read the variables that are in the loop (useing Template parser) but otherwise global, not values that are posted in the array that loop.. example:

```
# News_Controller.php

// load lang file /news_lang.php
$this->lang->load('news', 'english');

// push arrays of variables in content
$this->data['content'] = $this->parser->parse('news/edit_news_tmp', array_merge($this->data, $news, $this->lang->subset('text')), true);

// push content in main index template
$this->parser->parse('admin/index_tmp', $this->data);
```

Get `$news` as data array with details on two lang from Model_News.php:

```
$news = array(
  [idNews]    => 10
  [isActive]    => "checked"
  [details_news]    => Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [titleNews] => 'Hi, Im news title!',
        [shortLanguage] => 'ENG',
        [nameLanguage] => 'English'),
    [1] => Array(
        [titleNews] => 'Titre pour les nouvelles!',
        [shortLanguage] => 'FRA',
        [nameLanguage] => 'France'),

  )),
  [idNews]    => 11 
  ...
```

Lang file return key:
`['lang_txt_news_label_name'] = 'News title';`

```
// edit_news_tmp.php template looks like:

{details_news}
   <div class="form-group">
        /* lang key NOT shown in loop */
        <label>{lang_txt_news_label_name}</label> 
        /* value form array, shown OK */
        <input type="text" name="nameNews_{nameLanguage}" value="{nameNews}">
    </div>
{/details_news}

/* but it can be seen outside the loop */
<p>{lang_txt_news_label_name}</p> /* produce: Title */
```

variable that comes from model (nameLanguage, nameNews...) can be seen without problems.. but variables that are inserted in controller into the template (like _lang keys), through the parser, can not read in loop.

Does anyone know what could be?

In Codeigniter version 2.x I used the above method many times and it's always worked..

Thanks in advance..